# Qt - style change causes error (OpenType support missing)

Tags: qt, styles, qt-creator, opentype

I have a simple QlineEdit on my UI. It allows me to enter Hindi language characters (copy from google translator and paste) - (जॉन)

But when I change any of the style using stylesheet, for e.g. color changed to red. Now if I paste the same hindi language text (जॉन) it show cubes (boxes) in place of characters and I get output message "OpenType support missing for script"

Also I tried this using two edit boxes with one of it having color defined in style sheet, I see boxes on other edit box as well (even though I haven't touched its style at all)

There is no code required, just create hello world program, in designer add a editbox, defined 1 or more style e.g. color in stylesheet and try paste HINDI language characters "जॉन"

Could anyone help me on this.

Comment: do you bind a font to make sure you're always guaranteed being able to render your language of choice?

Comment: Qt 5, I am using. realized now that this issue is seen even without styles. SO its random. I started with hello world program with one ui element editbox to it. where I want to be able to paste hindi characters.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is - when you change widget's stylesheet your font changes to one, that doesn't support Hindi. In order to fix this, you need to find out, which font is used by Qt as default in your system and set it in the same stylesheet string.

Comment: Thanks for all responses. I tried by setting font and font family myself. But it now seems that this issues occurs even if I remove styles completely.

Comment: Now there is no style in my code, with this it worked once and not working now. Its completely random. How can there be an UI which accepts certain unicode character (Hindi in my case) once and not later. Am I missing anything ? would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Need more info on this. There should be something different between when it's working and when not. Nevertheless, I'm pretty sure, the reason is - the font you are using. It's the main thing, responsable for drawing glyphs.

Comment: I recreated new hello world app with just one editbox and it worked well. Added a button to show empty dialog, no other code. And copy paste of HINDI text to edit box started showing boxes again.

Comment: if i remove ui->lineEdit->setText(QObject::tr("जॉन")); again I see boxes only when i try paste HINDI text in editbox.  MY CONCLUSION : I need to load fonts, inspite that  Qt supports HINDI already and I need to set HINDI text to one of the similar widget. Now one will be able to use his other widget to do what he want to. VERY WEIRD.. but this is only scenario which worked consistent. Experts KINDLY suggest, where am I going wrong

Comment: also the text जॉन in this code statement     ui->lineEdit->setText(QObject::tr("जॉन"));     appears boxes on my QT creator editor

Answer (score 0):

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

```
QStringList fileList;
fileList<<"akshar.ttf"<<"DroidSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf"<<"aparaj.ttf";
fileList<<"chandas.ttf"<<"mangal.ttf"<<"Kruti_Dev_010.ttf";

QStringList::const_iterator constIterator;
for (constIterator = fileList.constBegin(); constIterator != fileList.constEnd(); ++constIterator)
{
    QFile res(":/new/prefix1/" + *constIterator);

    if (res.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        if (QFontDatabase::addApplicationFontFromData(res.readAll()) != -1) {
            qDebug()<<"successfully loaded font " + *constIterator;
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug()<<"failed to load font " + *constIterator;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        QString errMsg;
        errMsg = res.errorString();
        qDebug()<<"font file open failed  :  = " + errMsg ;
    }
    res.close();

    QFont font;
    font.setFamily("akshar");
    QApplication::setFont(font);
    // QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
}

ui->lineEdit->setFont(QFont("akshar", 10));
ui->lineEdit->setFont(QFont("mangal", 10));
ui->lineEdit->setText(QObject::tr("जॉन"));
ui->lineEdit->hide();
```

}![enter image description here][1]

This doesnt seem good solution, but for here through some trial and error. I am loading fonts (which to my knowledge Qt already supports) as with hello world program it works well until I add one button to UI.

What I am doing now ?
I am creating lineedit, setting font for it, and then setting a HINDI test on it. Then hide this LineEdit as I dont need it.

Because of doing all I mentioned above now my UI allows me to paste different language text on to other line edits on same UI screen - see attachment.

What I discovered seems stupid solution but without this line edit will show boxes for hindi text. I tested difference between my working hello world and non working hello world program using version control there is no difference in code, so somehow QT tool runtime forgets HINDI suddenly and then never understands it. But my work around make UI to understand HINDI and allied languages.